# Maven - Setting Parent Dependency Version in Child POM

Tags: maven, pom.xml

We've got a parent POM, in which we'd like to set a dependency, but no a *version* of that dependency. The idea is that it's a bit like an abstract member: we want to ensure that inheritors specify a particular instance of this dependency.

How would this best be achieved? We could set a default version in the parent, and if children want to override it then they could do so using `dependencyManagement`. Another possible solution is to use properties that are set in the child.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a dependency in `<dependencies>`, you have to set a (valid) version number. But, as you said, you can put the version number into a property. Child projects can then override this property if they need to. However, the parent project has a default version.

`<dependenyManagement>` is just used do declare dependencies. But it doesn't add dependencies to your project.